Microphone works on some apps but does not work on most apps

I am running Windows 10 on Lenovo V310 - 14KIB model laptop. My default built-in microphone works fine, loud and clear in, 
Windows Voice recorder, Zoom meetings and OBS recorder.
 But it doesn't work in other apps such as: 
Browsers (using Google Meet, Facebook), Messenger desktop App, WhatsApp web or desktop, discord, TeamViewer, Anydesk etc. 
I have restarted my computer several times, checked volume level as  mentioned here, and so on.

Nothing works. Is there any way to fix this issue?


How exactly it doesn't work?

@ChanganAuto no one can hear me. Voice speaking indicator in google meet or any social app remains silent. Sometimes microphone in messanger app for desktop works but sometime doesn’t.

That information should be added to the question by [edit]ing it.
